# jquery + coffeescript search box that hides list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, coffeescript

I am trying to create a search box that hides UL and LI elements depending on text.

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('input#barcode').on "keyup", ->
        search = $(this).val()
        $('li.barcode').each ->
            $(this).parent().fadeOut('fast') unless $(this).text().indexOf search == 0
```

I also want to know how to use fat arrows (=>) to make the code look better.

I've already fixed it!!

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('#barcode').on "keyup", ->
        search = $(@).val()
        $('.barcode').each ->
            $(@).parent().fadeOut('fast') unless $(@).text().indexOf(search) == 0
```

i still don't know how to use fat arrows. And i think it would make my code nicer. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Depending on what text? Can you describe better what are you trying to accomplish? It is not clear to me.

Comment: there is an input whose id is barcode. I want to write into this the product's barcode listed below it, and it action hides the products whose text isn't similar to the what a searched. The text is the value between the first <li> and </li> of each <ul>

Answer (score 0):

if you understand this [documention](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow), you will know how/why to use the `fat arrow`.

and you can try:

```
$ ->
    $('#barcode').on "keyup", ->
        search = $(@).val()
        $('.barcode').each ->
            $(@).parent().fadeOut('fast') unless $(@).text() is search
```